# Send 1 bookmark from IOS to Mac w/o iCloud or Email

Tags: ios, mac, applications, sharing, bookmarks

I do NOT want to sync all my bookmarks across all my devices via iCloud, etc. Far too many bookmarks on my Mac that don't need to be on iPad, etc.

But sometimes I find a site on my IOS device & I want to have that site bookmarked in my Mac automatically or at least send the site link to my Mac to put it into my Mac bookmarks folder later.  I can't find any way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can paste it into a note or calendar event if you sync those via iCloud.  Or you could send it to yourself via iMessage.

Answer (score 1):

[iCloud Tabs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5372) does exactly this, but there doesn't seem to be a way to enable only that feature without also enabling bookmark syncing. But it's well worth it: any tabs that are open on one device are automatically listed on all others, without you having to do a single thing.

On your iOS device, "iCloud Tabs" gets its own top-level folder in your bookmarks, so you can effectively ignore the bookmarks that are synced from your Mac.

Comment: I'd second the iCloud tabs use case for lightweight bookmark syncing. You could use the Reading List function to push a page onto that stack and then pop it off later, but that also has overhead of saving the article's text on each device. If your use case is occasional articles, that shouldn't be a big drawback.